# Confusion about unsigned and integer expressions

Tags: c, integer, expression, implicit-conversion, unsigned-integer

I have these logical expressions and I don't understand how to calculate them. Can someone help me? I understand that there is a conversion from an unsigned value to a signed value but how do you apply it?

```
int v=0xFFFD;
unsigned z=1;
(v+z)/2=32767
```

The result shows that number but the textbook doesn't explain why. Do you convert the value `v` from hexadecimal to binary? And after that step, what should I do? And here are 2 other examples with unsigned expressions:

```
(v+1)/2=-1
-1>z
```

How is that possible? How can you prove that?
There is something else. The hexadecimal form has 16 bits in binary.How can I use the sign bit method for the values I entered?

Comment: Hexadecimal is a display format.

Comment: The book in which these exercises appear should have stated a presumed width or size to use for the `int` type, and, depending on what that size is, it may have also stated the rule for converting unrepresentable values to the `int` type. Providing those statements is necessary to answer these questions without going into excessive detail about various hypothetical possibilities.

Comment: Only your third expression is true: [Live demo](https://tio.run/##jYvdCoIwGEDv9xQfi0ApyykktGY34VN0I9u0gc3Yj4TRsy@TLgs6l4dzeNJyHsJCad55IeFgnVD95lIipLSDa610NPRKxPBAMPGWA0vvVVWd6Gy8tqrVUsDICEWzupkpayK8tGeN1xANqzHeZsAY5NmuKOAI2BkvMewBN3VnJY7pj5F8xoT8fSWkHL/Hc22k80ZDStEzhBc)

Comment: (v+z)/2=32767 Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It only tells me the answer and not the method/proof.Is there a proof for what I wrote?

Comment: Since that v value is in the hexadecimal base do you have to convert it in the base 2?

Comment: Your system has 16 bit integers and uses 2's complement to represent signed integers.  If you understand that (and you're casting to an unsigned int in your examples), then everything should make sense.

Comment: Please check your numbers. `32677` is probably a typo for `32767`.

Comment: In base 2 the form of 0xFFFD is : 1111 1111 1111 1101. How is that going to help me?

Comment: @Paulpro How is 0xFFFD equal to these values?Is there a proof?

Comment: What about the second example? Is there a proof for that one?

Comment: The results depend on how big `int` is on your system. I think the examples assume that `int` is 16 bits (`INT_MAX==32767`). If so, please update your question to make that assumption explicit. And please change `32677` to 32767` **in the question** (acknowledging the error in a comment is insufficient).

Comment: What do you mean by "the sign bit method"?

Comment: @wolly: An 8-minute YouTube video with narration that's very difficult to understand is not an answer to the question. And you still haven't updated the question to indicate how big `int` is assumed to be.

Comment: @wolly With unsigned expressions the result can not be evaluated to -1.:)

Answer (score 1):

In this expression

```
(v+z)/2
```

the object of the type `int` `v` is converted to the type `unsigned int` due to the usual arithmetic conversions

so the value of the expression

```
v + z
```

is equal to (in the hexadecimal notation)

```
0x0000FFFE
```

(

```
ox0000FFFD
+
0x00000001
==========
0x0000FFFE
```

)

I assume that the size of an object of the type `unsigned int` (the same as the size of the type `int`) is equal to `4`.

Take into account that the value `0xFFFD` stored in the variable `v` is positive. If the size of the type `int` is equal to 2 then in this case the compiler would issue a warning or error because an object of the type int with 16 bits is unable to accommodate this value.

In C there is no negative integer constants. All integer constants are non-negative.

That is if you are using a declaration like this

```
int x = -1;
```

then in this declaration there is used integer constant `1` and the unary operator `-`. `-1` is an expression with the unary operator `-` operand of which is the integer constant `1`.

The expression

```
0xFFFFFFFE / 2
```

is equivalent to the expression

```
0x0000FFFE >> 1
```

So you will get

```
0x00007FFF
```

that is decimal is equal to `32767`

Gere is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int v = 0xFFFD;
    unsigned z = 1;

    printf( "%u\n", (v+z)/2 );
    printf( "%u\n", (v+z) >> 1 );
    printf( "%u\n", 0x00007FFF );
}
```

Its output is

```
32767
32767
32767
```

As for you question

> Do you convert the value v from hexadecimal to binary?

Then the hexadecimal notation is only used for convenience of programmers to simplify writing code. Internally the value is stored in a binary notation (usually  in two’s complement representation for integers)

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, we will assume:

- `int` and `unsigned` (a.k.a. `unsigned int`) are 16 bits.
- `int` uses two’s complement, and a conversion from `unsigned` to `int` produces the `int` represented by the same 16 bits that represent the `unsigned`. Notably, for `unsigned x` with values from 32768 to 65535, `(int) x` is `x`−65536.

Hexadecimal, decimal, and octal are notations for representing numbers. “0XFFFD” is not a number; it is a string of characters. It represents the number 65533. We presume the reader is sufficiently familiar with hexadecimal that an explanation of the specific calculations are not needed. The hexadecimal “0xFFFD”, decimal “65533”, and octal “0177775” are different strings that represent the same number.

In `int v = 0xFFFD;`, a compiler converts `0xFFFD` to a number, 65533. Since this number cannot be represented in an `int`, the compiler gives it the type `unsigned int`, according to the rules of C. Then this `unsigned` value of 65533 is used to initialize an `int`. This requires a conversion from `unsigned` to `int`. Per the above assumptions, the result is 65533 − 65536 = −3. Thus `v` is initialized to −3.

In `unsigned z = 1;`, `1` is an `int` with value 1, it is converted to `unsigned` unremarkably, and `z` is initialized to 1.

In `(v+z)/2`:

- `v` is an `int` and `z` is an `unsigned`. According to the rules of C, `v` is converted to `unsigned`. Converting −3 to `unsigned` produces 65533. (The rules specify that, in this case, 65536 is added to or subtracted from the value as many times as necessary to bring it in range of `unsigned`. One addition sufficed.).
- Then we have 65533 + 1, which is 65534.
- Then 65534 / 2 = 32767.

In `(v+1)/2`:

- `v` is an `int` and `1` is an `int`. According to the rules of C, we continue using `int`.
- `v` is −3, so we have −3 + 1, which is −2.
- Then −2 / 2 = −1.

In `-1>z`:

- `-1` is an `int` and `z` is an unsigned. According to the rules of C, the `int` is converted to `unsigned`. To do this, we need to add 65536 once, so −1 + 65536 = 65535.
- Then we have 65535 > `z`. `z` is 1, so this is 65535 > 1, which is true.

Answer (score 0):

The example appears to assume that `int` is 16 bits. (This is fairly unusual on modern non-embedded systems, but perfectly legal. `int` is more commonly 32 bits these days.)

```
int v=0xFFFD;
```

Given that `int` is 16 bits, `INT_MAX` is `32767`, or equivalently `0x7FFF`. The expression `0xFFFD` (equivalently `65533`) is of type `long int`, and is implicitly converted to `int`.

This conversion yields an implementation-defined result. It's very likely that the value stored in `v` will be `-3` (if the system uses the common 2's-complement wraparound semantics).

```
unsigned z=1;
```

This is nice and simple.  `z` is of type `unsigned int`, and its value is `1` (more precisely `1U`).

```
(v+z)/2=32767
```

Given the assumptions we've made so far, this is correct. (This is a mathematical equality, not a C expression; `=` in C is assignment). In `(v+z)`, the two operands are of different types, and have to be converted to a common type before the addition can be done. The rule is that the `int` operand is converted to `unsigned int` (see "*usual arithmetic conversions*"). Converting `-3` to `unsigned int` yields `65533`. So `(65533+1)/2` is `32767`.

```
(v+1)/2=-1
```

This is also correct, given the assumptions we've made above. `v` has the value `-3`. `(v+1)` is `-2`. `-2 / -1` is `-1`.

```
-1>z
```

And this is also correct. `-1` is of type `int`. `z` is of type `unsigned int`. The same *usual arithmetic conversions* are applied, so `-1` is converted to `unsigned int`, yielding `65535U`. Clearly `65535U > 1U`.

The example is a poor one, since it relies on unstated assumptions and implementation-defined behavior. If it explicitly stated that (a) `int` is 16 bits (specifically `INT_MAX==32767` and `UINT_MAX==65535`) and (b) unsigned-to-signed conversion has the common 2's-complement wraparound semantics, then it would be a much better example.